# Can vite package nodejs back-end projects?

Tags: node.js, package, bundler, vite

Can vite package back-end project such express or koa?
How can we pack a back-end nodejs project?

Comment: It is difficult without plugins

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Checkout https://github.com/axe-me/vite-plugin-node. Here the config from one of my projects:

```
  plugins: [
...VitePluginNode({
  adapter: 'fastify',
  appPath: './src/main.ts',
  tsCompiler: 'swc',
  exportName: 'main',
}),
```